# What is the difference between RouteArea and RoutePrefix using AttributeRouting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, attributerouting

So I have been using http://attributerouting.net/ and love it.  However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around when I should use RouteArea, or RoutePrefix, or both.

For instance, my thought is that with an API controller, use RouteArea("api"), and then for a prefix maybe use the main function of the controller?  Any clarification would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RouteArea is meant for use with MVC controllers, which have a formal concept of areas. In web api, just use RoutePrefix.

Comment: So for webapi controllers, just use prefix, but for mvc controllers, area.  When would it be appropriate to use them both?  One of the examples I saw on the site used both at once.

i.e.
    [RouteArea("Reporting")]
    [RoutePrefix("Sample")]

Comment: Use RouteArea if you mapping routes to an MVC area. Prefixes give you another layer of control. For instance: I have an Admin area in my MVC site, and that area has a UsersController. I would use RouteArea("Admin") to declare that the routes correspond to the Admin area (to help with MVC view resolution, etc). Additionally, the RouteArea attribute will prefix all routes with "Admin/". I would then also use RoutePrefix("Users") to tack on a prefix of "Users/" to the controller's routes. So I'd get routes like: "Admin/Users/Foo". This makes more sense if you have RouteArea on a base controller.

Comment: @spot I'm doing the same, although my inherited code is not using standard MVC areas. Still, I've created a base controller and have applied a [RouteArea("module")] to it, and then my inherited controllers have RoutePrefix attributes of their own. Of course, if I want to write it from scratch, I would use the standard areas.